# OSX slow netwerk setup after sleep when wired (wireless is fast)?

Tags: macos, network

When my mapro6,1 awakes from sleep it takes like 20-30 seconds before the network (and therefor Internet) is working, when i use WiFi its almost instant.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Wel, guess I found it.

I used a cross-cable (UTP), instead of a normal cable. Although it works fine, it seems the link negotiation takes a bit longer.